# Little confusion on erlang:now/0 manual

Tags: erlang

> Returns the tuple {MegaSecs, Secs, MicroSecs} which is the elapsed
>   time since 00:00 GMT, January 1, 1970 (zero hour) on the assumption
>   that the underlying OS supports this. Otherwise, some other point in
>   time is chosen. It is also guaranteed that subsequent calls to this
>   BIF returns continuously increasing values. Hence, the return value
>   from now() can be used to generate unique time-stamps, and **if it is
>   called in a tight loop on a fast machine the time of the node can
>   become skewed.**

What does the bold sentence means? I'm a few confused as my english is not very good:)
Does it mean the time line is ascending with 45 degrees or does it mean the performance of node will decrease if invoke `erlang:now/0` too often?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`erlang:now/0` is built so that it always returns an incremented number (that is, the `MicroSecs` will be always guaranteed to be bumped by 1). This is useful because it let's you use values return by `now()` as unique IDs in your system (at least during one session of the VM).

However, it also means that if you run a fast enough loop (that is, sometimes faster than 1 micro second per loop) you might "request" more micro seconds than there are available. So you will actually increment the time over it's current value! (which is of course, a very bad thing)

Comment: "(which is of course, a very bad thing)" - Not necessarily. Also note that it is hard to get into this position by running a tight loop. A more plausible situation is if you have multiple processes on a multicore machine.

Comment: @EmilVikström Can you give more details. For example, won't this situation happen on a single core machine?

Comment: A microsecond is a rather short period of time. I am able to get the behavior you are asking about (the microsecond part incremented by one) by creating the tuple `{now(), now(), now(), now(), now()}` which usually gives increasing numbers. If I, however, throw in a simple calculation in there: `{now(), now(), 5+1, now(), now(), now()}`, we see that the calculation will take a few microseconds. I have a hard time imagining when this would be an issue on a singlecore machine, at least if you are doing anything meaningful at all in your loop.

Comment: @EmilVikström It's always a "bad thing" to skew the system time, many libraries and maybe parts of your system depend on it. Running a tight loop is only one example of how to get there.

Comment: Adam, then use `os:timestamp/0` as suggested by the manual page for `now/0`.